# Browser is not displaying images

Tags: html, css

For some reason any of the programs is displaying any images,

```html
<img src=""  width="" height="" alt="" >
```

I was working a couple days ago, am I missing something?? 
Did the syntax changed recently?
The page is loading everything else, but no images.

I used sublime text and Visual studio.
I tried to open it with Opera and Chrome. Nothing !!!!!

Comment: Sounds like a path issue.

Comment: Please read your own question again yourself and try to understand it like someone who doesn't know what you're currently trying to do. From the code you've given us, you'd think "well of course it doesn't display any images, because all the attributes of the img tag are empty!". Try to rephrase your question so anyone trying to help you can actually understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="https://aaronlilly.github.io/Pokemoncomparisongame/6.jpg"  width="50px" height="50px" alt="pokemon" >
```

Works fine for me.